# Cordova 5.2 opens links in external browser

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing an android/phonegap app in Cordova 5.2. The problem is that although the app launches correctly and displays the login page, upon submitting the form I get the android dialog asking to confirm which browser I want to use to view the page.

I don't want that to happen, I just want the phonegap webview to handle it in the app.

The login page is set to the location of the page on the server side, not a local html page, so I don't really understand why it's doing this.

Here is the form, it's as simple as it can possibly be:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="formContainer">

      <form id="login" action="<?=URL::to('authenticate')?>" method = "POST">

        <input type="text" name="loginUser" id="loginUser" placeholder="Username"  >
        <input type="password"  name="loginPass" id="loginPass" placeholder="Password" >
        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>

    </div> 

</body>

</html>
```

The only other part that's customised following the install command is the config.xml file that defines the launch file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.spinner.jrcm" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>JRCashManager</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <!--<content src="index.html" />-->
    <content src="http://jcash.spinner.co.uk/mobile" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />

    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've added the code above, thanks

Comment: If login page is online use inAppBrowser to display it

Comment: Thanks, tried it but it's the same - although not surprised because I've set the launch page to a public URL before with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can add following code in cofig.xml:

`<allow-navigation href="*" />`

note:By default in cordova5.2 ,it add plugin 'cordova-plugin-whitelist' to cordova project,this problem can be solve by using whitelist plugin,you can read more detail by youself.